# Error: No matching signature for function IF for argument types: BOOL. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to count the number of times a "rating" is above 9. Working in Google BigQuery with StandardSQL

I previously was using a CASE WHEN function but wanted to change it to an IF as there is only one case. Previous code which worked fine:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (survey_responses.survey_rating  >= 9) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
   AS survey_responses_num_positives
```

Current code

```
SELECT 
COUNT(IF(survey_responses.survey_rating  >= 9),1,NULL)
   AS survey_responses_num_positives
```

The current code spits out the error:

`No matching signature for function IF for argument types: BOOL. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) at [11:39]`

Don't really understand it as the IF statement is a BOOL value no? Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using  "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM survey_responses WHERE survey_rating > 1"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the full code as the rest wasn't relevant. But there are several other IF statements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missplaced a parenthesis:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(IF(survey_responses.survey_rating  >= 9,1,NULL))
   AS survey_responses_num_positives
```

`IF` takes 3 arguments, the condition, if true, and else.

Comment: happens, though questions like yours could be considered as off-topic, be careful onwards

Answer (score 4):

Use `COUNTIF()`!

```
SELECT COUNTIF( survey_responses.survey_rating >= 9 ) AS survey_responses_num_positives
```

BigQuery has this built-in as a convenient function.  I recommend using it.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation :

```
SELECT IIF ( @a > @b, 'TRUE', 'FALSE' ) AS Result;
```

So

```
IIF(survey_responses.survey_rating  >= 9 ,1,NULL)
```

Not sure if this works ! So let me know